# Spring REST Many To Many with an extra column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, rest

I have three Entities in my Spring-Boot Application:

Recipe N->1 RecipeIngredient 1->N Ingredient

It corresponds to a many to many relationship. However, the RecipeIngredient has an extra field "quantity".

I am trying to link together my table so that I can get a Recipe with its ingredients and their quantities.

So far I have this code:

### **Recipe**

```java
@Data

@Entity
@Table(name="recipe")
public class Recipe implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="duration")
    private int duration;

    @Column(name="created_on")
    private LocalDate created_on = LocalDate.now();

    @Column(name = "preparation")
    private String preparation;

    @Column(name = "difficulty")
    private int difficulty;

    @Column(name = "serving")
    private int serving;

    @Column(name = "pricing")
    private int pricing;

    @JsonManagedReference("recipe")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RecipeIngredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    public Recipe() {
    }

    public Recipe(String name, int duration, LocalDate created_on, String preparation, int difficulty, int serving, int pricing) {
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.created_on = created_on;
        this.preparation = preparation;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.serving = serving;
        this.pricing = pricing;
    }
}
```

### **Ingredient**

```java
@Data

@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredient")
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference("ingredient")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList<>();

    public Ingredient() {
    }

    public Ingredient(int id, String name, List<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
    }
}
```

### **RecipeIngredient**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe_ingredient")
@Data
public class RecipeIngredient implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    public RecipeIngredientId recipeIngredientId = new RecipeIngredientId();

    @JsonBackReference("recipe")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("recipe_id")
    private Recipe recipe;

    @JsonBackReference("ingredient")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("ingredient_id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    @Column(name="quantity")
    private String quantity;

    public RecipeIngredient() {
        System.out.println("[RecipeIngredient] no args constructor called");
    }

    public RecipeIngredient(Recipe recipe, Ingredient ingredient, String quantity) {
        this.recipe = recipe;
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

### And finally RecipeIngredientId

```java
@Embeddable
public class RecipeIngredientId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int recipe_id;
    private int ingredient_id;

    public RecipeIngredientId() {
    }

    public RecipeIngredientId(int recipe_id, int ingredient_id) {
        this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
        this.ingredient_id = ingredient_id;
    }

    public int getRecipe_id() {
        return recipe_id;
    }

    public void setRecipe_id(int recipe_id) {
        this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
    }

    public int getIngredient_id() {
        return ingredient_id;
    }

    public void setIngredient_id(int ingredient_id) {
        this.ingredient_id = ingredient_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        RecipeIngredientId that = (RecipeIngredientId) o;
        return recipe_id == that.recipe_id &&
                ingredient_id == that.ingredient_id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(recipe_id, ingredient_id);
    }
}
```

In my browser, can request all recipe and I obtain the following:

[image: All recipes]

Ideally, I would like to obtain ingredients like:

```
...
"ingredients": [
    {
        "name": "salad",
        "quantity: 2
    }
]
```

Finally, is it possible with Spring / Hibernate to create a new Recipe, and add it new ingredients in a single request ? Or should I create the ingredients first and then pass them to the recipe ?